# C# Adding Value to My List Items

Tags: c#, webforms

C# question, I'm using a query string to pass information from one page to another.  I'm attempting to add a value to my drop down list.  I'm struggling to figure out how to do it.  I've tried multiple things, but thought that an if else statement might solve my problem.  It didn't.  Can anyone help me add a value to my list?

```
using System;
System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (!this.IsPostBack)
        {
            DropDownList1.Items.Add("Concert-Guns N Roses");
            DropDownList1.Items.Add("Concert-Katy Perry");
            DropDownList1.Items.Add("Performance-Blue Man Group");
            DropDownList1.Items.Add("Comic-Howie Mandel");
            DropDownList1.Items.Add("Circus-Barnum and Bailey");
        }
    }

    protected void BtnViewCart_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        {
            if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 0)
            {
                DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "75.00";
            }
            else if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 1)
            {
                DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "65.00";
            }
            else if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 2)
            {
                DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "40.00";
            }
            else if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 3)
            {
                DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "28.00";
            }
            else if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == 4)
            {
                DropDownList1.SelectedValue = "25.00";
            }
            decimal gnrTicket = Convert.ToDecimal(DropDownList1.SelectedValue[0]);
            decimal kpTicket = Convert.ToDecimal(DropDownList1.SelectedValue[1]);
            decimal bmgTicket = Convert.ToDecimal(DropDownList1.SelectedValue[2]);
            decimal hmTicket = Convert.ToDecimal(DropDownList1.SelectedValue[3]);
            decimal bbTicket = Convert.ToDecimal(DropDownList1.SelectedValue[4]);
        }
            if (DropDownList1.SelectedIndex == -1)
            {
                labelError.Text = "You Must Select a Show!";
            }
        else
        {
            string url = "Output.aspx?";
            url += "Item=" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Text + "& <br />";
            url += "Price=" + DropDownList1.SelectedItem.Value + "& <br />";
            url += "Mode=" + RadioButton1.Checked.ToString();

            Response.Redirect(url);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: it may help http://csharp.net-informations.com/gui/cs-combobox.htm

Comment: why you set selected value after click? If you check selected index (how you do) then you can set only value to property and not modify the listbox values. How @Jim McFetridge said, you can set value on listbox creation but if you don't provide value you can check index and set result property.

Comment: The problem is that I've only learned how to do things a certain way, so I kinda am working with those restrictions.  I'm trying to teach myself new things that I haven't learned yet, but am failing.  I know what I want to do, but that doesn't convert to correct programming language.  For example, You're telling me to not set selected value after click, but I'm not sure where the correct place to set it is.

Comment: I said, Jim answear is good. When creating elements. The best approach is to create elements as needed before adjusting them later because is easy to create new one than finding what next you need to do. Your learning approach is good and you are welcome GL ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As a good practice, it is probably best not to try to resolve this in the Click event handler, and to simplify the code. We can do this by learning more about the ListItem class. (See MSDN for more information.)

In one of its overloads, a ListItem has two components -- a text value and a data value. For example:

```
// Create a ListItem
ListItem li = new ListItem("MyText", "MyValue");

// Add it to the DropDownList
MyDropDownList.Items.Add(li);
```

Therefore, you can save having to do all of that logic in the Click event handler by assigning the values with their label counter parts.  Your values are numeric in your code above, but you can parse them to Decimal or Double data types later.

You can do the above in one step if you wish.  I just expanded it to illustrate.  For example:

```
DropDownList1.Items.Add("Concert-Guns N Roses", "75.00");
```

Does this help?

Comment: Two more questions.  I can actually set the text and value properties in the web form.  First question:  What would I put after my if (!this.IsPostBack) to make it work doing that way.  Second question:  I've tried to call the value from a list and couldn't figure it out.  What is the correct syntax to get a value from a list.  For example :  Is it DropDownList1.SelectedValue?